# "host in..." or "host at..."?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct way of using the word "host" as a verb? Should I be using "at" or "in"?

Ex:

> He hosted the party at his house. They host parties at the gym.
>
> He hosted the party in his house. They host parties in the gym.

Would there be any difference if the sentence was switched to 3rd person?

Ex:

> The party was hosted at his house.
>
> The party was hosted in his house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Host as a verb should take an object, like "host the party," etc. Typically I believe you would encounter "at" rather than "in," unless you wanted specifically to draw attention to the notion that it was inside the building instead of outside.

"The after game party will be hosted *in* the school" (to clarify it will not be outside). Likewise, you could say, "the after game party will be hosted outside the school," if that (being outside) is what is meant. But generally, where it is a general location that only one locale can be implied there, "hosted at" would be the most natural way to say this.

Comment: great explanation!